# summary(randomforest) - how to read?

Tags: r, random-forest

Here is my code:

```
library(randomforest)
fit <- randomforest(var_1~.,data = mydf, ntree=100, importance =TRUE)
summary(fit)
```

Here is how output looks:

```
                Length Class  Mode     
call                 5 -none- call     
type                 1 -none- character
predicted       322479 factor numeric  
err.rate           300 -none- numeric  
confusion            6 -none- numeric  
votes           644958 matrix numeric  
oob.times       322479 -none- numeric  
classes              2 -none- character
importance          24 -none- numeric  
importanceSD        18 -none- numeric  
localImportance      0 -none- NULL     
proximity            0 -none- NULL     
ntree                1 -none- numeric  
mtry                 1 -none- numeric  
forest              14 -none- list     
y               322479 factor numeric  
test                 0 -none- NULL     
inbag                0 -none- NULL     
terms                3 terms  call
```

Where can I find explanation of summary?

Comment: I guess you mean random forest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `summary` for `randomForest` is not implemented well / is not consistent with summary on other models. It is just printing out some internal variables, their type and length. The details of the internal variable can be found [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)

We can get some (minimal) information by `print(fit)` and more details by using `fit$forest`. The original code by Leo is written in Fortran and current implementation is using C++ by Andy. Some discussions can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037859.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. On Leo Breiman page I cannot seem to find what `call` is (the very first line of the summary). Did you mean to say 'is not implemented well'?

Comment: @user1700890 Yes. I mean summary for RF is not as good as summary for other models. Or it does not comply with `R` "summary standards"